Trying to get libsndfile to build as a static lib with vorbis (ogg) support with cmake, but vorbis isn't found
I'm trying to add libsndfile to my project to play ogg files. I've added libogg, libvorbis and libsndfile to my cmake build but libsndfile still doesn't have ogg support.
# Fetch libogg
FetchContent_Declare(
    libogg
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/xiph/ogg.git
    GIT_TAG v1.3.5
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(libogg)

# Fetch libvorbis
FetchContent_Declare(
    libvorbis
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/xiph/vorbis.git
    GIT_TAG v1.3.7
)
SET(OGG_INCLUDE_DIR ${libogg_BUILD_DIR}/include)
SET(OGG_LIBRARY ${libogg_BUILD_DIR}/libogg.a)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(libvorbis)

# Fetch libsndfile
FetchContent_Declare(
  libsndfile
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile.git
  GIT_TAG        1.2.0 # Replace with the version you need
)
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF CACHE BOOL "Build shared libraries" FORCE)
SET(Vorbis_Vorbis_LIBRARY ${libvorbis_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libvorbis.a)
SET(Vorbis_Vorbis_INCLUDE_DIR ${libvorbis_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(libsndfile)

when running cmake .. in my build folder I can see the libsndfile output doesn't have vorbis support, event with Vorbis_Vorbis_LIBRARY and Vorbis_Vorbis_INCLUDE_DIR set.
-- 
CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/libogg-src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Configuring libogg 1.3.5
CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/libvorbis-src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Configuring vorbis 1.3.7
-- Found Ogg: /libogg.a
CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/libsndfile-src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/libsndfile-src/CMakeLists.txt:14 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0091 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Could NOT find ALSA (missing: ALSA_LIBRARY ALSA_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found Ogg: /libogg.a (Required is at least version "1.3")
-- Could NOT find FLAC (missing: FLAC_LIBRARY FLAC_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find Opus (missing: OPUS_LIBRARY OPUS_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find mp3lame (missing: MP3LAME_LIBRARY MP3LAME_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find Mpg123 (missing: MPG123_LIBRARY MPG123_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.25.10")
-- Could NOT find Speex (missing: SPEEX_LIBRARY SPEEX_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- The following features have been enabled:

 * INSTALL_PKGCONFIG_MODULE, generate and install pkg-config module
 * INSTALL_MANPAGES, install man pages for programs

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * LibUSB
 * Nettle (required version >= 3.0)
 * GnuTLS
 * OpenSSL
 * BZip2
 * LibLZMA (required version >= 5.2)
 * zstd (required version >= 1.3.6)
 * SQLite3, light weight SQL database engine., <www.sqlite.org/>
   Enables regtest

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * ZLIB
 * Ogg, library for manipulating ogg bitstreams, <www.xiph.org/ogg/>
   Required to enable Vorbis, Speex, and Opus support

-- The following features have been disabled:

 * BUILD_SHARED_LIBS, build shared libraries
 * ENABLE_EXTERNAL_LIBS, enable FLAC, Vorbis, and Opus codecs
 * ENABLE_MPEG, enable MPEG audio (including mp3) codecs
 * ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL, enable experimental code
 * BUILD_TESTING, build tests
 * BUILD_REGTEST, build regtest
 * ENABLE_CPACK, enable CPack support
 * ENABLE_CPU_CLIP, Enable tricky cpu specific clipper
 * ENABLE_BOW_DOCS, enable black-on-white html docs
 * ENABLE_PACKAGE_CONFIG, generate and install package config file

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * webp
 * MbedTLS (required version >= 1.0)
 * PulseAudio
 * OSS
 * AudioIO
 * JACK
 * OpenSL
 * PortAudio
 * MySOFA
 * SndFile
 * ALSA
 * Mpg123 (required version >= 1.25.10)
 * Speex, an audio codec tuned for speech, <www.speex.org/>
   Enables experemental Speex support

-- The following RECOMMENDED packages have not been found:

 * Vorbis, open source lossy audio codec, <www.vorbis.com/>
   Enables Vorbis support
 * FLAC, Free Lossless Audio Codec Library, <www.xiph.org/flac/>
   Enables FLAC support
 * Opus, Standardized open source low-latency fullband codec, <www.opus-codec.org/>
   Enables experimental Opus support
 * mp3lame, High quality MPEG Audio Layer III (MP3) encoder, <https://lame.sourceforge.io/>
   Enables MPEG layer III (MP3) writing support

What am I doing wrong?

"I can see the libsndfile output doesn't have vorbis support, even with Vorbis_Vorbis_LIBRARY and Vorbis_Vorbis_INCLUDE_DIR set." - I guess that you have found out these variable names from the output like Could NOT find Vorbis (missing: ...). Now this output is not shown to your, because FindVorbis.cmake script suppress its own output when found one of required variables is already set. Comment out this suppression, and check output again.

(For change content of libsndfile project, clone it locally, and specify path to that clone with SOURCE_DIR option to FetchContent_Declare. That way FetchContent will use your local clone of the repository instead of cloning the project from the remote server.)

@Tsyvarev - removing the two SETs does bring back the error Could NOT find Vorbis (missing: Vorbis_Vorbis_LIBRARY Vorbis_Vorbis_INCLUDE_DIR Enc)  But that's why I set them in the first place, to tell where vorbis is located. So I removed them and have the error again, but still no ogg support in libsndfile.
I'm trying not to have things cloned manually, that's why I have it setup to pull from git.

"I'm trying not to have things cloned manually ..." - But you currently in the debugging stage. You are trying to convenience FindVorbis.cmake script to interpret that you have Vorbis installed, while you actually are only building it (with FetchContent). On that way nothing wrong to make manual steps, which wont be present in production.

You have set two variables - Vorbis_Vorbis_LIBRARY and Vorbis_Vorbis_INCLUDE_DIR - while the error message contain three things. There Enc is the name of component requested for Vorbis package (via find_package(Vorbis COMPNENTNS Enc)). For "fake" this component you need to find out how the Find script marks the component to be found: https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile/blob/1.2.0/cmake/FindVorbis.cmake#L151

@Tsyvarev - I completely missed the Enc. Setting them as well get me closer. Thank you much.
